# If a database ref requires the user to be authenticated to read or write will signing out automatically cancel any listening at that location?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Say I have the default database rules.

```
{
  "rules": {
     ".read": "auth != null",
     ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

And a listener.

```
firebase.database.ref('/foo').on('value', snap => {
  console.log(snap);
});
```

If the user signs in and starts listening at 'foo', then signs out do I still need to call

```
firebase.database.ref('/foo').off()
```

Or will the listening be canceled automatically?

Answer (score 2):

I just tested it with this code:

```
auth.signInAnonymously().then(user => {
  console.log('signed in');
  ref.on('value', 
    snapshot => console.log('got value: '+snapshot.val()),
    error => console.error(error)
  );
  setTimeout(
    () => auth.signOut().then(() => console.log('signed out')), 
    5000);
});
```

This prints:

> signed in
>
> got value: value

And then a few seconds later

> signed out
>
> [object Error] {
>     code: "PERMISSION_DENIED"
>   }

So it looks like authenticated listeners are cancelled when you sign out.

Comment: Does this mean that listeners are cancelled? I thought it means that it is listening the ref but due to permission denied it could not read or write the data.

Comment: If you sign-out, you lose access to data that requires you to be signed in, so the listeners are cancelled. I recommend setting up a jsbin and testing it: if you change he value after the error callback is called, the listener won't be called anymore..

Comment: It looks like the listeners are not cancelled, if you sign back in again the listeners continue to fire, even if you don't call them again.

Comment: I  just expanded my test snippet to sign the user in again and it doesn't pick up changes after that happens. Which is in line with how I expect the Firebase clients to work: one a listener is cancelled, it is unregistered. Note that the behavior is different if the token *expires* while the client is offline. In that case the client will try to refresh the token when it comes back online and won't immediately cancel the listeners. But calling `signOut()` (as you asked about and my code shows) cancels the authenticated listeners.